# Get iframe content by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a HTML file named `test.html` and below are the content of that file.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    This is the content.
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have another file where I want to show the `test.html` content by iframe and then match the content with something and do something if it matches.

Here is what I'm trying but I'm not getting the iframe data.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="test.html"></iframe>
    <script>
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
        var iframe_content =  iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        var content = iframe_content;

        // var content = "This is the content."; --> I want to get the iframe data here like this. Then match it with the following.

        var find = content.match(/ is /);
        if (find) {
            document.write("Match Found");
        } else {
            document.write("No Match!");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: it doesn't work.
I also tried 
`iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]innerHTML;`

Comment: Is `iframe_content` `undefined`?

Comment: it shows `No Match!` in the browser

Comment: Try executing your script after the document has loaded.

Comment: So what is the value of `iframe_content`?

Comment: I tried  `document.write(iframe_content);`
But it doesn't show anything on DOM or console

Comment: Most likely you just need to wait for the `load` event of the iframe.  Put all of your existing code inside a `document.getElementById("myIframe").addEventListener('load'` event handler.

Comment: Nothing shows on DOM, but on console I got this error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at HTMLIFrameElement`

if I use `iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;` .
and shows this error `index.html:8 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLIFrameElement.`
if I use this `iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;`

Comment: The code worked after I run it from XAMPP htdocs. The original post code works and also the other answers. Thanks everyone.

But can anyone tell me why it wasn't working while it was not run from XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you need to wait for the `iframe` content to load. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

```html
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525117/get-iframe-content-by-using-javascript#"></iframe>
<script>
  const myFrame = document.getElementById('myIframe');
  myFrame.addEventListener('load', (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.target === myFrame);
    console.log(evt.target);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Nothing will work unless your web page and iframe have the same origin

Comment: The URL in the question is a relative one. They do have the same origin.